# manipulating javascript date objects

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to manipulate a javascript date object, to increment it by one day:

```
var now = new Date(+1 day);
```

What are the javascript options for something like this...

EDIT: cheers

Comment: i see the same answer is given three times in 1 min. If that isn't fast!

Comment: @Tim I was used to waiting at least a half hour for a good programming answer. Now its rare that I go 10 minutes. I've never found any other Q&A community that gives answers of such high quality in so little time. :D

Comment: @Tim: Reputation and Badges have created a monster!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
var now = new Date();
now.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
```

`setDate` will correctly convert January 32 into February 1.

Comment: for some reason I had the impression this wasn't doing what it should be. Of course it was, and my error was elsewhere. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
var myDate=new Date();
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+1);
```

setDate will increase the current date with 1, hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Some straightforward answers have been posted, but just do you know, W3Schools has a fantastic Javascript date object [reference page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).

Comment: W3Schools isn't great.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/date

Comment: …and is totally unrelated to **W3C**. Moreover, you should have posted this as a comment, not as an answer to this question.